# Need help for DB structure

Tags: database

In my application user can post questions and comments. each question has many comments and a comment is belongs to a question. This application may have millions of users.we have to extract tags from the questions and comments.

Now we planned to have db structure like this.

1. questions table(id,question)
2. comments table(id,comment)
3. tags table (id,tag_name)
4. tags_questions_comments (id,tag_id,question_id,comment_id)

Now I am having a confusion whether this is correct or not ?.

```
id  tag_id     question_id comment_id   
--------------------------------------
1   1          1           NULL         -> tag from question  
2   2          1           NULL
3   3          1           1            -> tag from comment
```

Thanks

Comment: More appropriate for [dba.se]?

Answer (score 0):

I would make two tables instead of:

`tags_questions_comments (id,tag_id,question_id,comment_id)`

The one includes the set:

```
tags_questions (tag_id,question_id)
```

And another one for the the comments:

```
questions_comments (question_id,comment_id)
```

unless you add a `questionId` columns to the comments table which could be a better approach according to your needs.

Comment: thank you TwoMore. I added the question_id in comments table.Happy to hear that my approach is correct :)